# Excel concat issue

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, comparison

I have a list of open close time for a point of sale, separated by columns. I have to manually go through the list and convert the open close time separated by columns to a string that looks like this MON - FRI 8:30 - 17:00, SAT 9:00-13:00, SUN closed.

Is there a way to automate this process. So far i was not successful with CONCAT and IF with multiple conditions. Sorry, i do not have this much exp with excel functions.

I understand there is a need for excel to somehow compare data by rows and if the data is the same print the specific content like `=IF(AND(A2=C2; A2=E2; A2=G2; A2=I2); "A2"; "NO")`. I most definitely wrong, since it didn't work.

Additional problem is that using CONCAT and IF with time turns the time into the number. Overloading the IF with `TEXT(A2; "hh:mm:ss")` didn't help.

[image: What the data looks like]

Example of the table is here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b_C7u4UDBESywU8Qe_HRuhTLySZSAcn5a-t87yCcb_s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, you don't give example data to work with so I won't test. owever you could do something like "=A1&" - "&B1 etc

Comment: Added the link to google sheets. Can you please elaborate on "=A1&" - "&B1. I tried concatenating the data.

Comment: Keep using the & and add characters and cells as needed,